# Determining the interest rate necessary to retain a certain balance after sixty monthly withdrawals

Tags: calculation, interest-rate, withdrawal, spreadsheet

I have seen many examples online for "Time Value Money" and "sinking funds". I want to know how I can combine any type of solver in the PMT-PV equation? Because all these examples have known FV, PV, and i (interest rate) and they all solve for PMT, but I want to solve for i.

Example: I have 10 million in the bank account, and I want to have 5 million in the balance of the account after 5 years. I want to make a withdrawal of 100 thousand every month (end of month), so I have to know what interest rates I am seeking for so this would work for me.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to solve the [money-weighted return equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Internal_rate_of_return).  It cannot be expressed as a formula for the interest, but it *can* be solved numerically as shown here.

Using the OP's figures, with monthly withdrawals of $100,000.

The summation for the withdrawals can be replaced with the [standard annuity formula](http://www.financeformulas.net/Present_Value_of_Annuity.html).  The resulting monthly return is converted to a [nominal annual return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) compounded monthly.

*Money-weighted return equation with start and end balances `s0` and `s1`*

[image]

The interest is 2.63282 % per annum, nominal compounded monthly.

*Selectable equation*

```
10000000 - (100000 - 100000 (1 + x)^-60)/x - 5000000/(1 + x)^60 = 0
```

[image]